# How do I get country specific results when using iGoogle?

Tags: google-search, locale

Since I signed up for iGoogle, my search results have become less useful. Before, results would be weighted towards my locale - UK - so that I'd get shopping results in pounds, and .co.uk sites first. Now when I search for things, I get prices in dollars or US specific sites.

For example, if I search for "Linksys WRT54GL", the first result is for [Amazon.com](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BTL0OA)

I have checked through the options. No luck.

How do I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried going to `http://igoogle.co.uk/` and was redirected to `http://www.google.co.uk/ig?hl=en`.

Might that work for you? There's a "Pages from the UK" option, so it seems to be localized.